# PHP XML Parsing

Tags: php, xml

I am making get request in PHP but the parser is having issues. I am looking for a way to retreive the value of URL in the following example. The response xml looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<testtemplate JobName="test1">
<Sources>
 <Source xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/test/schema/api">
    <System>
      <SystemIdentifier>HTTPS</SystemIdentifier>
      <URL>http://example.com</URL>
    </System>
 </Source>
</Sources>
<testtemplate>
```

and my PHP code looks like this:

```
$xml = DOMDocument::LoadXML($response);
$mypath = new DOMXPath($xml);
$mypath->registerNamespace("a", "http://www.microsoft.com/test/schema/api");

$url = $mypath->evaluate("/testtemplate/Sources/Source/System/URL");
$message = $url->item(0)->value;

print($message);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Ashish

Comment: What are the "issues" it is having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample XML is malformed (the `testtemplate` is not closed), assuming that is just a typo lets get on to fixing your main issue.

You'll need to use that namespace which was registered in order to access the elements within it, and the DOMElement from `item(0)` does not have a `value` property (`nodeValue` is used instead).

```
$xml = DOMDocument::LoadXML($response);
$mypath = new DOMXPath($xml);
$mypath->registerNamespace("a", "http://www.microsoft.com/test/schema/api");

// These two lines have changed, slightly.
$url = $mypath->evaluate("/testtemplate/Sources/a:Source/a:System/a:URL");
$message = $url->item(0)->nodeValue;

print($message);
```